# openacc and cache tilling

Tags: optimization, blocking, openacc

-----   example code   -----------

```
for (body1 = 0; body1 < NBODIES; body1 ++) {
   for (body2=0; body2 < NBODIES; body2++) {
     OUT[body1] += compute(body1, body2);
   }
}
```

-----    blocking  code------

```
for (body2 = 0; body2 < NBODIES; body2 += BLOCK) {
   for (body1=0; body1 < NBODIES; body1 ++) {
      for (body22=0; body22 < BLOCK; body22 ++) {
         OUT[body1] += compute(body1, body2 + body22);
      }
   }
}
```

I insert OpenACC directives to offload code to GPU.
But the performance was decreasing.
I search some paper,and they conclude the reason is that OpenACC can not take advantage of shared memory in GPU. But I think the main reason is that the tilling/blocking prevent the parallell. Because the tilling bring data dependence.
If the OpenACC do not supply or not encourage code tilling?
If there is a solusion or example that tilling tech improve the OpenACC code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenACC can do automatic and explicit tiling (via the tile clause) however, I don't think this is your issue.  The problem I see is that the body2 loop is not parallelizable due to the dependency on "OUT[body1]".  OpenACC can perform scalar reductions in parallel, hence you might try the following:

```
  #pragma acc parallel loop 
  for (body1 = 0; body1 < NBODIES; body1 ++) {
    sum = 0.0;
  #pragma acc loop reduction(+:sum)
    for (body2=0; body2 < NBODIES; body2++) {
      sum += compute(body1, body2);
    }
    OUT[body1] += sum;
  }
```

Granted, I'm guessing here so if this does not help, please post an compliable example of the issue.  If you are using PGI, please post the compiler feedback messages (-Minfo=accel) as well.